# Configure and control a large website through a property file

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am doing a relatively large website with Spring MVC. Many places in the website need to be configured. For example: character-length, max numbers allowed, etc. Here is what I am doing now.

I have a property file called conf.properties, which contains, for example, the following data:

```
age.min=13
```

I also have a Java class called Conf.java, which reads conf.properties and provides to other classes configuration/control data (such as minimum age) via static methods. For example:

```
static {
    bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("conf.properties");
}

public static getAgeMin() {
  return Integer.valueOf(bundle.getString("age.min"));
}
```

Is this a good practice for managing the configuration of a large website? What are other approaches? I understand that storing all these config data in database could be one, but not sure whether people normally use it.

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include your properties to spring bean and wired it in your java file.

```
<bean id="properties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath*:conf.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Then in your java file that you want to use the properties file, you would just use below's sample code

```
@Controller
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    private Properties properties;

    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public String showMain(ModelMap model) {
        Integer ageMin = properties.getProperty("age.min");
        // .. DO YOUR PROCESSING
    }
}
```

This is how we do our configuration for our production site. We also did use database to store some of the configuration. But only for property that need to be change frequently. For those property that might not need to be change frequent, personally I think configuration file is the best.

Comment: khairul, thanks for sharing your Spring bean approach.I am interested in it. For "@Autowired private Properties properties", you don't need to identify the bean using bean id? What is the benefit of having a Spring property bean? Besides, you have to define " @Autowired private properties properties;" everywhere you use. It seems my approach of using Conf.getAgeMin() is simpler and clearer. I feel that I may have missed something. Thanks for helping out!

Comment: The wired property variable 'properties' in the java file must use the same naming as the one that is defined in the bean. Actually, for production, we use single instance of property holder class like what you have, but we use @Autowired to load the properties file. Yes, I do agree with you, its simpler and clearer, plus, more controllable in case you want to refactor the property key. :)

Comment: One more, we have multiple properties file to load. So by doing this, we only need to add the properties file name to the bean location list in the xml and all of the properties will be loaded to the single variable that you wired in the java file.

Comment: khairul, thanks so much for your follow-up. I learned from your answer and comments, and they will surely help others Cheers!.

Answer (score 1):

Resource bundles are meant to provide that type of configuration content, so it is certainly a possible thing.  It also has some nice provisions for i18n so it can make it easier to provide different language dependent strings as well, which may tend to be a bit less natural to configure in a database table.

Personally, I do prefer having my configuration files since it makes it easier to modify and update and since they're just plain text files, you can easily generate them or access them with scripts and other tools.

Comment: subdigit, thanks for chiming in! Glad that you pointed out the benefits of using a property file..